# How can we return the K Nearest neighbour in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

The KNeighborsClassifier from sklearn predicts the class calculating the k instances that have the least distance, right? But, can we return the instances that he is using to do this prediction?

for instance:
if knn calculate that Ana should be a woman due the distance from Mary and Alexa, can we return ['Mary','Alexa']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the method [kneighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors), that returns indices of and distances to the neighbors of each point.

First, you need to fit the algorithm on the training dataset, then you can ask to give `k neighbors` for some specific items.